# Lua: performance of __index as a function vs as a table

Tags: performance, lua, complexity-theory, time-complexity

In Lua the [the __index metamethod](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html) can be either a function or a table reference. So the following constructions are equivalent:

```
foo = { a=1, b=2, c=3 }
bar = setmetatable({}, {__index = foo})
baz = setmetatable({}, {__index = function(_,x) return foo[x] end })

print(bar.a) -- 1
print(baz.b) -- 2
```

It would seem that the `baz` implementation would be slower.

But how much slower?

I don't care much about implementation differences. What I'm looking for is the 'general' comparative difference. Are we talking about a linear increment, one order of magnitude, or several orders?

To give some context: I'm developing [a oop library](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass) where in the most common circumstances (95%) a table is enough. But there's one specific case in which I need a function. Knowing the difference will help me decide whether to 'split' the library in two (one fast and covering 95% of the uses, and one module that uses functions for the rest) or just dumping the table option in favor of the function.

This particular __index is used extensively (every time an instance method is invoked).

If that helps, the function I'll be using will be very small, similar to this:

```
function __index(t,x) return foo[x] or bar[x] end
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you profile it yourself?

Comment: I could profile it on my computer, but I'm not really interested in "how fast is the implementation on an Ubuntu machine with x processors and x RAM". I want to know how different they are *algorithmically*.

Comment: So ... let me see if I get this right.  You're not interested in what its performance is in the real world, only in its hypothetical performance.  Check.

Comment: I was interested in knowing the orders of magnitude - as in O(n) vs O(n²). Individual results on machines would not help me very much to get that. Maybe my English wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Algorithmically they are they same. They both resolve to the same hashtable lookup, average time O(1). The difference is constant, mostly from the function call overhead.

On my machine the closure is ~2.2 times slower than the metatable lookup (which is 2.5 times slower than a direct lookup). Testing on [Codepad's server](http://codepad.org/gWfTwRK0), the difference is ~2.

Bottom line, on a fast machine (circa 2010), the function call is adding about a tenth of a microsecond of constant overhead, otherwise the performance is the same.

BTW, much LÖVE from Mud. :)

Comment: :) thanks a lot for your kind response. Now that I have a figure in mind, I can decide.